# Adding Bank Account in Stripe.NET for Managed Account

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

I've searched through the documentation on both the Stripe website and JaymeDavis' GitHub and still cannot manage to figure out if I'm correctly creating a bank account for a managed stripe account.  From Stripe's website, it's clear this is what I need...

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts/acct_1032D82eZvKYlo2C/external_accounts \
   -u sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: \
   -d external_account=btok_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have the token (btok....) returned from Stipe.js, and I have the account ID used in the curl link for the managed account, as well as the secret key.  However, I cannot figure out what the process is to execute this in C#

My guess so far has been:

```
    //Sample code for creating a managed account
    StripeAccountService stripeAccountService = new StripeAccountService();
    StripeAccountCreateOptions managedAccountCreateOption = new StripeAccountCreateOptions();
    managedAccountCreateOption.Managed = true;
    managedAccountCreateOption.Country = "US";

    StripeRequestOptions connectAccountRequest = new StripeRequestOptions();
    connectAccountRequest.ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiKey"];
    Stripe.StripeAccount response = stripeAccountService.Create(managedAccountCreateOption, connectAccountRequest);

    // ADD Bank Account
    var myAccount = new StripeAccountUpdateOptions();
    myAccount.ExternalBankAccount.TokenId = "SampleToken";

    var accountService = new StripeAccountService();
    Stripe.StripeAccount bankAccount = accountService.Update(response.Id, myAccount);
```

The problem I'm having here is with adding the bank account.  I want to create the bank account separately so that I can save the last 4 digits of a card/bank account (non-sensitive data) used in payouts in our database.  The way above simply adds a single bank account to the managed user, and will not work as I would like to add multiple bank accounts for payouts.  Any sample code in adding a bank account to an already existing managed account would help immensely (i.e. create a bank account with the token returned from Stripe.js, then in a separate action add this bank account to the managed user account so that I can grab the last 4 digits of this bank account as well as any additional accounts that are added in this way in the future). Thank you in advance for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just retrieve a Managed Account instead of creating one, i.e.:

StripeAccount response = accountService.Get(accountId);

From there you can [add additional Bank Accounts](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#creating-a-bank-account).  The result of that API call is a `BankAccount`, and you should be able to [access the `last4`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_bank_account_object) from there.

Comment: So just to double check, should I create a CustomerBankAccount type for a managed account? Or just a general BankAccount because it seems like there are multiple types of bank accounts in stripe.net. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If I had to guess - which is what I'm doing :D - I'd say a 'general BankAccount'.